# Looking for the name of a chart

Tags: charts, data-visualization

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I didn't know where else to ask. I have two dimensions: **Shoe company** (Nike, Adidas,s etc) and **Shoe type** (Trainers, pumps etc). I have one metric **Shoes sold**.

I want to create a chart similar looking to a Sunburst chart however the two dimensions are not hierarchical. I couldn't find what I was looking for so drew a picture, please excuse my lack of artistic talent. Does anyone know what a chart like this would be called, or where I could go about making one (preferably excel but any language would do (I can learn it if needed))

[image]

Comment: Maybe [donut chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not a chart type that Excel can create as an all-in-one chart. That said, you can still make that chart with a few simple workarounds.

The approach is basically to create two pie charts and put one over the other. To make the one you posted, you'd just have to create a standard pie chart for shoe company info. Then create another (smaller) pie chart for shoe type. Drag the shoe type chart over the shoe company chart.

(You can also use a doughnut chart for the same effect: https://best-excel-tutorial.com/56-charts/209-multi-level-pie-chart)

Comment: The problem with that is the inner pie chart is just a pie chart, I would want it split up so each Shoe company section is split up with its correlating Shoe type. So out of "Adidas", their were 20% Trainer, 20% Chelsea boot etc. And so on for each section. So in the inner pie chart, a category would show up more then once.